# Trouble updating entity in EF Core

Tags: postgresql, asp.net-web-api, entity-framework-core

I'm trying to write a ASP.NET web api with EF 7 and Postgres. I have a function that is supposed to add an upvote to a post.

```
  [HttpPost("{id}/Votes")]
    public async Task<ActionResult> PostVote(PostVoteDTO voteDTO)
    {
        PostVote vote = voteDTO.Convert();
        Post post = await _dbContext.Posts.FindAsync(voteDTO.PostID);
        if (post == null)
        {
            return NotFound("Post not found");
        }
        post.Votes.Add(vote);
        post.Content = "Upvoted";
        _dbContext.Posts.Update(post);
        await _dbContext.SaveChangesAsync();
        return Ok();
    }
```

This currently is not working. It adds an upvote to my table of post upvotes and updates post content, but it does not add to post.Votes when I make a GET posts request. The following code has relevant model definitions and the GET posts request. Thanks!

Get Request

```
 [HttpGet(Name = "GetPosts")]
    public async Task<List<Post>> GetPostsAsync()
    {
        return await _dbContext.Posts.ToListAsync();
    }
```

VoteDTO

```
public class VoteDTO
{
    [Required]
    public UpvoteScore Value { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public int UserID { get; set; }
}

public class PostVoteDTO: VoteDTO
{
    [Required]
    public int PostID { get; set; }

    public PostVote Convert()
    {
        PostVote postVote = new PostVote();
        postVote.PostID = PostID;
        postVote.Value = Value;
        postVote.UserID = UserID;
        return postVote;
    }
}
```

Vote Model

```
public abstract class Vote
{
    [Required]
    public UpvoteScore Value { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public int UserID { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("UserID")]
    public User Voter { get; set; } = null!;
}

[PrimaryKey(nameof(PostID), nameof(UserID))]
public class PostVote : Vote {

    [Required]
    public int PostID { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("PostID")]
    public Post Post { get; set; } = null!;
}

public enum UpvoteScore: short
{
    Downvote = -1,
    Upvote = 1
}
```

Post model

```
[Index(nameof(Title), IsUnique = true)]
public class Post
{
    public int PostID { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public int PosterID { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("PosterID")]
    public User Poster { get; set; } = null!;

    public DateTime PostTime { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(5000)]
    public string Content { get; set; } = null!;

    [Required]
    [StringLength(200)]
    public string Title { get; set; } = null!;

    public List<PostVote> Votes { get; set; }
    public List<Comment> ChildComments { get; set; }

    public Post()
    {
        Votes = new List<PostVote>();
        ChildComments = new List<Comment>();
        PostTime = DateTime.UtcNow;
    }
}
```

EDIT**

At the suggestion of Svyatoslav, I added change debugger tracking. The function now looks like this.

```
[HttpPost("{id}/Votes")]
    public async Task<ActionResult> PostVote(PostVoteDTO voteDTO)
    {
        PostVote vote = voteDTO.Convert();
        Post post = await _dbContext.Posts.FindAsync(voteDTO.PostID);
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(_dbContext.ChangeTracker.DebugView.LongView);
        if (post == null)
        {
            return NotFound("Post not found");
        }
        post.Votes.Add(vote);
        post.Content = "Upvoted Test2";
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(_dbContext.ChangeTracker.DebugView.LongView);
        await _dbContext.SaveChangesAsync();
        return Ok();
    }
```

The output is as follows

```
Post {PostID: 1} Unchanged
  PostID: 1 PK
  Content: 'Upvoted Test'
  PostTime: '12/8/2022 2:51:09 PM'
  PosterID: 1 FK
  Title: 'bob title'
  ChildComments: []
  Poster: <null>
  Votes: []

Post {PostID: 1} Unchanged
  PostID: 1 PK
  Content: 'Upvoted Test2' Originally 'Upvoted Test'
  PostTime: '12/8/2022 2:51:09 PM'
  PosterID: 1 FK
  Title: 'bob title'
  ChildComments: []
  Poster: <null>
  Votes: [<not found>]
```

So the list of votes goes from empty to to a list containing not found?

EDIT 2**

I realized that EF core was not tracking the vote, but it was adding it to the DB. Instead of adding the vote to the post.Votes, I simply added it to _dbContext.PostVotes. EF now tracks the changes to Post.

Code

```
[HttpPost("{id}/Votes")]
    public async Task<ActionResult> PostVote(PostVoteDTO voteDTO)
    {
        PostVote vote = voteDTO.Convert();
        Post post = await _dbContext.Posts.FindAsync(voteDTO.PostID);
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(_dbContext.ChangeTracker.DebugView.LongView);
        if (post == null)
        {
            return NotFound("Post not found");
        }
        await _dbContext.PostVotes.AddAsync(vote);
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(_dbContext.ChangeTracker.DebugView.LongView);
        await _dbContext.SaveChangesAsync();
        return Ok();
    }
```

Comment: Try instead of `FindAsync` -  `await _dbContext.Posts.Include(p => p.Votes).FirstOrDefaultAsync(p => p.Id == voteDTO.PostID)`

Comment: Thanks for the attempt, but sadly it doesn't work. I'm finding the right post and updating it as the content change is working, but the list change isn't. I think I may need to do something with the relationship configuration. I'll update the post if I figure it out.

Comment: Remove `_dbContext.Posts.Update(post);` it is not needed and my cause problems.

Comment: Still not working. I only added that in an attempt to get EF to track the post

Comment: Check this one: [Change Tracker Debugging](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/change-tracking/debug-views)

Comment: Thanks for the tip. The change tracker is showing that the Votes list goes from empty to containing not found. See the edit for the details.

Comment: 1) Use `FirstOrDefaultAsync` with `Include` 2) remove `Update`.

Comment: Also check which query tracking behavior do you have or simply `await _dbContext.Posts.AsTracking().Include(p => p.Votes).FirstOrDefaultAsync(p => p.Id == voteDTO.PostID)`

Answer (score 0):

You need to include the Votes in the Get request.

```
    [HttpGet(Name = "GetPosts")]
    public async Task<List<Post>> GetPostsAsync()
    {
        return await _dbContext.Posts.Include(p => p.Votes).ToListAsync();
    }
```